CSS display grid is not working on Mobile Safari
What I want is an image grid with squares, and the images are centered within that square. See example which is working on the desktop.
Searched with google and stackoverflow, but can't find the answer. Who knows, why is this not working on Mobile Safari 17.4.1. (It's working on Chrome, Firefox, Edge etc.)
FYI: When I run the code snippet on desktop it's working, when I open stackoverflow on mobile and also run the snippet, it's not working.


.grid {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(150px, 1fr));
        grid-gap: 4px;
    }

    .grid::after {
        display: none;
    }

    .grid-item {
        aspect-ratio: 1;
    }

    .grid-item>img {
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        min-height: 100%;
        min-width: 100%;
        display: block;
        object-fit: cover;
    }
   <div class="card">
    <div class="grid">
        <a class="grid-item" data-gallery="gallery-1" href="https://picsum.photos/600/900">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="img">
        </a>
        <a class="grid-item" data-gallery="gallery-1" href="https://picsum.photos/600/900">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/500" alt="img">
        </a>
        <a class="grid-item" data-gallery="gallery-1" href="https://picsum.photos/600/900">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/300" alt="img">
        </a>
        <a class="grid-item" data-gallery="gallery-1" href="https://picsum.photos/600/900">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/200" alt="img">
        </a>
        <a class="grid-item" data-gallery="gallery-1" href="https://picsum.photos/600/900">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/1200" alt="img">
        </a>
        <a class="grid-item" data-gallery="gallery-1" href="https://picsum.photos/600/900">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/500" alt="img">
        </a>
        <a class="grid-item" data-gallery="gallery-1" href="https://picsum.photos/600/900">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="img">
        </a>
        <a class="grid-item" data-gallery="gallery-1" href="https://picsum.photos/600/900">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/500" alt="img">
        </a>
        <a class="grid-item" data-gallery="gallery-1" href="https://picsum.photos/600/900">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/300" alt="img">
        </a>
        <a class="grid-item" data-gallery="gallery-1" href="https://picsum.photos/600/900">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/200" alt="img">
        </a>
        <a class="grid-item" data-gallery="gallery-1" href="https://picsum.photos/600/900">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/500/1200" alt="img">
        </a>
        <a class="grid-item" data-gallery="gallery-1" href="https://picsum.photos/600/900">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/1200/500" alt="img">
        </a>
    </div>
</div>




Based on my experience, some code properties aren't universally supported across platforms. One workaround is using flex boxes for arranging multiple items side by side. You can apply display: flex to the main div class and flex-grow: 1 to the sub div classes. For mobile devices, consider using the column property since grids in rows might not display well. Utilizing media queries to adjust viewport and properties for different devices can simplify this process. For instance, setting properties to trigger at a minimum width of 600px can enhance compatibility.
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  /* Your CSS properties for devices with a minimum width of 600px */
}

Hope this helps :)
